# performance difference for jquery selectors for checkbox

Tags: jquery, performance

What is the difference in performance between 
`$("input[name='Is_checked']")` and `$("#Is_checked")`
where

```
<input id="Is_checked" name="Is_checked" type="checkbox" value="true">
```

also the best practice between these two methods

Comment: Is there a reason you care about the performance of a selector? Both will be very, very fast. The ID selector should be faster, but does that really matter in your application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The super fast selector would be ID. So ans is,

```
$("#Is_checked")
```

[image: Performance]

### [Perfomance test](http://jsperf.com/jquery-selector-perfomance-with-id-and-name)

Comment: The ID selector is faster because it uses the JavaScript core method `getElementById`

Comment: @silentw talking more generic..specific (id, find) selector are the fastest one..

Answer (score 0):

Best practice is probably to use `:checked` if you want to select all checked checkboxes.

```
$('input:checked')
```

http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/

Or to use `.is(':checked')` if you want to see if a specific checkbox is checked.

```
$('input').is(':checked')
```

Performance wise it won't make much difference between the above or your variations, so you should just use the one best suited for your situation. For example, using `ID` to tell if something is checked might not be a good idea because of duplicate `ID`'s.

But if you still want to know the difference in performance between your two examples, selecting by `ID` is faster. Here you have some statistics that you might find interesting:

http://jsperf.com/id-vs-class-vs-tag-selectors/2